# How to make restful service calls to update the column of dataframe fast(er)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We need to call an external restful service to update the column value in a `Dataset`. We are using a UDF function to make restful service calls which is very slow.

```
dataset.withColumn("upper", upperUDF('call restful service'))
```

It's a sync call, that took ~1 hour and 10 minutes for 25,000 accounts (each account issue a call).

How to make it faster?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend converting the `Dataset` to an `RDD` using `Dataset.rdd` and then `RDD.foreachPartition`.

```
val names = Seq("hello", "world").toDF("name")

scala> names.show
+-----+
| name|
+-----+
|hello|
|world|
+-----+

scala> names.rdd.foreachPartition(p => p.map(n => "call restful service for " + n).foreach(println))
call restful service for [hello]
call restful service for [world]
```

You could then think of a local cache for the same entries to avoid time-expensive restful service calls.

---

From the comments:

> how does this improve the performance?

1. `RDD.foreachPartition` gives you access to all elements as an iterator (lazy and memory-friendly) so you could avoid external calls by using a local cache (per partition or per executor so all partitions / tasks that are executed on an executor can use the cache).
2. The number of partitions can be changed to avoid too many parallel external calls (DDOS). Use `RDD.repartition` or `RDD.coalesce` operators. Moreover you could control the number of partitions by the data source you use to read the dataset from.

> How to update the corresponding column after the get the response back from API

Since you left Dataset API and want to use RDD API for external calls, the question is how to go back from RDDs to Datasets. That is as simple as `RDD.toDF(comma-separated column names)`. The columns have to match the RDD representation and is up to the case class of the RDD.

Comment: Thanks, Jacek. Really appreciate. But, how does this improve the performance? And, another question is can we customize the number of partition on specific operator like Apache Flink? So, we can slow down the call to avoid the exceed TPS issue in API side.

Comment: Another question is how to update the corresponding column after the get the response back from API

Comment: @JacekLaskowski this is an efficient analysis of the problem!

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BrianZ Please accept if you like the answer or ask away to get an even better answer :) Thanks.